# need help for json format

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, format

I need help to change `json` format from this

```
{"aaData":[["<\/i><\/a> \r\n <\/i><\/a>",["00404","smith","20000000.00","75000.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","3500.00"]]]}
```

to

```
{"aaData": [["<\/i><\/a> \r\n <\/i><\/a>", "00404", "smith", "20000000.00", "75000.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "3500.00"]]}
```

thanks

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $aRow) {
$row = array();

$btn = '<a class="btn btn-smd btn-primary" href="cgajikaryawan/edit/'.$aRow['id'].'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a> 

<a class="btn btn-smd btn-danger" href="cgajikaryawan/delete/'.$aRow['id'].'" onclick="return confirm(\'sure?\')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>';

$row = array_values($aRow);
$output['aaData'][] = array($btn,$row);

}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please tag the question with what language you're using.

Comment: remove [] near "00404", codeigniter by the way

Answer (score 0):

foreach ($query->result_array() as $aRow) {

$row = array();
$btn = ' 
                    ';

$row = array_values($aRow);

$output['aaData'][] = array($btn,$row);
}

echo json_encode($output);

Comment: If this is your code, you should make an edit to your question which includes this. Only answers go in the answers section.